# How to separate function mocks of two classes that implement the same interface?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

My problem is defined in header, actually. I am writing unit tests with Junit, PowerMock&Mockito. I am mocking a class like that,

```
class User{
       public final synchronized String enter(AbstractClass ac){
       //.....
       }
}

// In test function
User mockUser = PowerMockito.mock(User.class);
PowerMockito.when(mockUser.enter( Mockito.any(Class1ImplementsSameAbstract.class)))
            .thenReturn("Some Str 1");
PowerMockito.when(mockUser.enter( Mockito.any(Class2ImplementsSameAbstract.class)))
            .thenReturn("Some Str 2");

System.out.println(mockUser.enter(new Class1ImplementsSameAbstract()));
System.out.println(mockUser.enter(new Class2ImplementsSameAbstract()));
```

How can I separate these two "when" conditions? When I run this test, both of the "System.out.." lines print "Some Str 2".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `any*` family of matchers do not do type checking, you should use [`isA(Class<T>)`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Matchers.html#isA%28java.lang.Class%29) instead:

```
PowerMockito.when(mockUser.enter(Mockito.isA(Class1ImplementsSameAbstract.class)))
        .thenReturn("Some Str 1");
```

Or alternatively, use the actual arguments, e.g.:

```
final Class1ImplementsSameAbstract klass1 = new Class1ImplementsSameAbstract();

PowerMockito.when(mockUser.enter(klass1)).thenReturn("Some Str 1");
```